# Put a view in the center and fit the top and bottom in the remaining space

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a squareView that when put on the layout makes a square view that has the length of the width of the screen

I have 3 views the squareView and 2 other views lets call them view1 and view2

I want the squareView to be in the center of the screen and view1 and view2 fit to the remaining empty space in top and bottom of the squareView

and what I tried so far didn't succeed

what I tried was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ice"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/frame1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/sky" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/undo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/undobutton" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/undo"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/lines" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menubutton" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a151e1f9140523a"
    ads:loadAdCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>

<layouts.Board
    android:id="@+id/board1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
</layouts.Board>
```

please any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two ways: RelativeLayout or LinearLayout.

With RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="..."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.your.package.SquareView
    android:id="@+id/viewCenter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/viewCenter"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FF0000" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewCenter"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#FF0000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

With LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FF0000" />

 <View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FF0000" />

<com.your.package.SquareView
    android:id="@+id/viewCenter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FF0000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it, this should work

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/viewCenter"
    android:background="#FF0000" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/viewCenter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewCenter"
    android:background="#FF0000" />
```